# Setting @Binding variable in swift doesn't change the variable for some reason

Tags: swift, swiftui

My code is as follows:

```
class EditorWindow: NSWindow {
    @Binding var keycode : Int

    override func keyDown(with event : NSEvent) {
        super.keyDown(with: event)

        print("before", self.keycode, Int(event.keyCode))
        self.keycode = Int(event.keyCode)
        print("after",  self.keycode, Int(event.keyCode))
    }

    init(keycode : Binding<Int>){
        self._keycode = keycode
        super.init(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
                   styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
                   backing: .buffered, defer: false)

    }
}
```

for detecting key-presses in an osx app. It detects the keypresses, but for some reason it doesn't set the keycode @binding variable (i.e. the value doesn't change in the 'before' and 'after' print statements), how can this be possible?

Edit: For clarification, the keycode variable I am passing in during init is a @State variable:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var keycode : Int = 0
    ...
}
```

...

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!
    ...

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let contentView = ContentView(userData: UserData(text:""))
        window = EditorWindow(keycode: contentView.$keycode)
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably it would be better in your case the approach based on `ObservableObject` as @EnvironmentObject for ContentView and pass its reference into EditorWindow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Binding` variable must be bound to something (eg. `@State`), like

```
struct TestNSWindowBinding: View {
    @State var keyCode: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        Text("Current key: \(keyCode)")
            .onAppear {
                let window = EditorWindow(keycode: self.$keyCode)
                window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
            }
    }
}
```

If it is not bound it just provide own initial state, consider it as external storage, so if no bound then no place to store value, so only default can be returned.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Though, my @ Binding variable is bound to a @ State variable - I edited my question to show how it is bound (in a potentially problematic way?)

Comment: You are not allowed to use @State outside of View (Apple recommends always mark it as private to avoid temptation to use it in wrong way), so your initialization must be reversed somehow (eg. as shown).